# How to get the name of a entity a ray or a ray sensor collides with?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In my sensor plugin, I have a ray sensor which casts a single ray. From this ray, I would like to get the name of the entity with which the ray intersects.

I have a working workaround by creating a test_ray (*physics::RayShapePtr*) and calling **test_ray->GetIntersection()** every time my ray measures a finite distance. However, it doesn't feel like the right way to do and furthermore, I get occasional segfaults which are caused somehow by underlying collision checks of the test_ray->GetIntersection() call.

Is there a better way to get the entity name?

In my plugin I have access to the parent ray sensor which is of type *sensors::RaySensorPtr*. From the parent sensor I can access the LaserShape (physics::MultiRayShapePtr), but apparently not the single ray (tried *getChild(0)* already).

Cheers,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12982/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-entity-a-ray-or-a-ray-sensor-collides-with?/) by [Hans-Joachim Krauch](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2536/hans-joachim-krauch/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm currently looking at Gazebo default, which may not match with your version of gazebo.
I think you can use the following API calls:

1. `physics::MultiRayShapePtr RaySensor::LaserShape() const`
2. `RayShapePtr MultiRayShape::Ray(const unsigned int _rayIndex) const`
3. `void RayShape::GetIntersection(double &_dist, std::string &_entity)`

An implementation might look like:

```
RaySensorPtr mySensor;
double dist;
std::string entity;

// Should check these pointers for NULL
mySensor->LaserShape()->Ray(0)->GetIntersection(dist, entity);

std::cout << "My ray intersected entity[" << entity << "] at a distance of[" << dist << "]\n";
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hans-Joachim Krauch](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2536/hans-joachim-krauch/) on 2016-04-04**:
Ah ok, I see you have added this functionality in Gazebo 7. I'm bound to 6.5 however (forgot to mention this), but it helps me anyway, thanks a lot!